# How long would it take to heal from a flogging in a medieval setting, with the best medical care available?

Tags: wound-care, wound, trauma

I'm writing a short story in a medieval fantasy setting in which a character is badly beaten, to the point of unconsciousness. Assuming his survival, approximately how long would it realistically take for him to to heal to the point of resuming normal activities?

Specifics: The character is an adult male in his 30s, he's strong and healthy. He's been manacled to a chain hanging from the ceiling and severely beaten by professional soldiers.
Afterward, he's being carefully tended by an experienced healer/herbalist, but obviously they don't have antibiotics, blood transfusions, etc. Medicine is things like herbs, honey, vinegar, broths, etc.

I'm eyeballing about 2 months, based on [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_(slave)), but I don't know if that's realistic. I've tried just generally googling this question, but most of the results are either about BDSM, or otherwise assume that I'm asking about modern medicine, so I'm having difficulty finding a good answer. Those that do mention a more medieval time period really don't give an answer, or say that these floggings were intended to kill.

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask- I originally posted in Writing and was advised to ask here instead.

Comment: Assuming no infection of the wounds (unlikely with non-sanitized whip/cat) then they will take as long as the body normally takes to heal such abrasions. This would depend on the extent of the skin and underlying tissue damage, but somewhere in the 6-8 weeks range would be not unreasonable for full recovery. [A modern case](https://theconversation.com/repeated-floggings-will-put-raif-badawis-life-at-risk-36317)